# Problem with c# telegram bot token processing

Tags: c#, json, exception, bots, telegram

I am writing a small telegram bot that would pull articles from Wikipedia. I am passing the token as a string. But when trying to process the token, an error occurs:

**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "JSON integer 6076351611 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'result.id', line 1, position 36."**

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;

namespace WikiBot
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private static readonly Random random = new Random();

        static async Task Main()
        {
            var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("6076351611:AAHOpSdOQl0Mi6WUGFV_otVZH_M81IdplvM");
            var me = await botClient.GetMeAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello, my name is {me.FirstName}!");

            botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
            botClient.StartReceiving();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            botClient.StopReceiving();
        }

        private static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs update)
        {
            if (update.Message.Type != MessageType.Text)
                return;

            if (update.Message.Text == "/wiki")
            {
                var articleTitle = await GetRandomArticleTitleAsync();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(articleTitle))
                {
                    var articleUrl = $"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{articleTitle.Replace(" ", "_")}";
                    await ((TelegramBotClient)sender).SendTextMessageAsync(
                        chatId: update.Message.Chat,
                        text: $"Here's a random Wikipedia article for you: {articleUrl}",
                        disableWebPagePreview: true);
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetRandomArticleTitleAsync()
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=1&format=json");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JObject.Parse(json)["query"]["random"].ToObject<List<JObject>>()[0];
            return result["title"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feoJn.png)

How can I fix this error? I understand why it occurs, but due to inexperience I can not overcome it.

Comment: The mapping to int should be to long

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 16.0.2 version of Telegram.Bot NuGet package, worked for me.
After this version there are new ways to do this stuff.